# Authenticated encryption and OpenSSL keys

Tags: openssl, cryptography, aes

So the main question is "can I store an OpenSSL private key (specifically an RSA private key) using authenticated encryption?".

OpenSSL supports a wide variety of encryption options for keys, however it seems like many of them are only supported as outputs, not inputs. For example, `openssl genrsa -aes256` works fine and creates a key that you can decrypt and use later (but is using CBC mode), but if you do `openssl genrsa -aes-256-gcm` the resulting key cannot be used by OpenSSL. The exact error message appears to vary by version, latest 1.1.0h gives:

```
root@cb772d20894d:/# openssl genrsa -aes-256-gcm | openssl rsa
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
.................................................+++
................................................+++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Enter pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase:
Enter pass phrase:
unable to load Private Key
139772421357760:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:445:
```

While older versions don't even get that far with:

```
140678952371864:error:0906B072:PEM routines:PEM_get_EVP_CIPHER_INFO:unsupported encryption:pem_lib.c:544:
```

The same error is shown with `aes-256-ocb` and `aes-256-ccm`. I think that's all of the available authenticated ciphers? Mayhaps I've missed an option somewhere in OpenSSL to allow this?

Comment: Using GCM mode from the CL with OpenSSL is broken.  You can't encrypt arbitrary data using GCM mode with OpenSSL either.  You might be better of encrypting it yourself manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some spelunking through the OpenSSL code reveals that the EVP key encryption layer doesn't understand auth tags, so they just get thrown away rather than stored with the IV as one might expect. As such, no AEAD cipher will work with the key encryption system at this time.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL maintains an internal table of digest algorithms and ciphers. **Prior to version 1.1** we need explicit initialisation or de-initialisation of this table. So, in order to add all algorithms, you need to call `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()` (which will add all algorithms to the table (digests and ciphers)). This will solve your unsupported encryption error.

Note: Make sure that you call `EVP_cleanup()` to remove all ciphers and digests from the table.

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant, it's a bug (or limitation, if you prefer) in the OpenSSL command line tool.